# Mystery Character (Components: 禾日日皿)

Tags: character-identification

I have a mystery character that I cannot seem to find the usual way: OCR, radical search, stroke search, nor drawing in any IME pad.

It appears to have 18 strokes in total and composed of **禾日日皿**. The middle two components can be tricky, as they may be **曰** also.

The character in question: [image: mystery character]

The character in question came from this particular page: [http://wu-chinese.com/minidict/search.php?searchkey=馚&searchlang=zaonhe](http://wu-chinese.com/minidict/search.php?searchkey=%E9%A6%9A&searchlang=zaonhe)

Comment: Why do they use PNGs for everything? So bizarre.

Comment: They wanted to prevent automated scripts from scraping their site. But I managed to do so anyhow and now I have a few images (out of thousands) which I do not have the Unicode code points for. I wrote some simple OCR code and heuristics to do a lot of the tedious work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

馧（yun1）means aroma.
馚馧(fen1 yun1) has the similar meaning.

Comment: That was totally looking under the wrong radical then. It seems that the radical is 香 plus 昷 (9 strokes) although the actual character seems to be considered a combination of 香 and  (10 strokes). It seems odd that the two variants would have different code points in Unicode!

Comment: @KevinLi they don't have different code points in Unicode. If you see 昷 in 馧 then you're using a Mainland Chinese standard font to display the character.  is seen in 馧 if you're using any other (Taiwan, Hong Kong, Japanese, Korean) font. See [this](http://www.zdic.net/z/28/zy/99A7.htm).

Comment: @droooze: Oh no. I was speaking of 昷 (U+6637) versus  (U+25055), which have different code points while all the variants of 馧 share (U+99A7). There is, however,  (U+2FA05), but that is in the compatibility ideograph range.

Comment: I tested the 馧 (U+99A7) in different fonts, and it did have slightly different glyphs depending on the font used. But 昷 (U+6637) remained distinct from  (U+25055).  (U+2FA05) did not render in Microsoft Word.

Comment: @KevinLi That's because 昷 and  are different glyphs (according to historical dictionaries) but the variations on 馧 are not.

Comment: @droooze: It seems to me that components are as different as many of the simplified versus traditional pairs. But then again, I don't write the criteria for assigning code points in Unicode. I just consume the end product. :\